# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths causes cell to blink or flicker

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, timer

I have a tableview where each cell contains the ability to play back an audio file.I'm trying to duplicate the cells found in the the voice memo program:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/J9d5ECM.png]

I'm using a UISlider to provide the playback bar and I have text labels for current time and time left. I would like the data in the cell to be updated while it is playing.

To animate the UISlider I call the method:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(player.duration) - Double(player.currentTime), delay: 0, options: .AllowUserInteraction | .BeginFromCurrentState, animations: {
    cell.audioSlider.setValue(Float(self.duration) - Float(self.player.currentTime), animated: true)
    self.startToPlay = false
}, completion: { _ in
    cell.audioSlider.setValue(Float(self.player.currentTime), animated: true)})
```

For the time I'm using a timer:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(interval), target: self, selector: "updateProgressBar:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Where the updateProgressBar function is intended to update the text labels.
If I call the reload method at every interval of the timer then the cell blinks.

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([currentCellIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

Is there a way to update values in the cell without calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`?

Answer (score 1):

Store a reference to the cell (NSIndexPath) you're wishing to update labels on then edit them directly.

Returns the table cell at the specified index path.

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  Parameters
  indexPath
  The index path locating the row in the receiver.

Return Value
An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

**Something similar this this.**

```
SomeCell *cell = (SomeCell*)[self.yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_yourStoredIndexPath];
cell.someLabel.text = @"Some text";
```